# Accessing array elements within process substitution bash

Tags: bash, curl, array, input, file-descriptors

I've got a text file which looks like this:

```
b4238ca2-cb8d-11e4-8731-1681e6b88ec1,https,username,password,ipaddress    
b4238f0e-cb8d-11e4-8731-1681e6b88ec1,https,username,password,ipaddress
b4239058-cb8d-11e4-8731-1681e6b88ec1,https,username,password,ipaddress
```

NOTE: username, password and ip address have all been changed, so as not expose sensitive info, they are real in my text file I'm using.

I've written the following bash scripting to read line by line and put each item into an array. Previously this worked, however now it is within a process substitution, it's not longer working. I'm assuming it's to do with how I am accessing the array elements, but I'm not sure what is wrong. Snippet below:

```
i=0
declare -a devices

while read line
do
    devices[i]=$line
    ((i++))
done < test_data.txt
timestamp=$(date +"%s")
echo "${devices[@]}"
IFS=","
declare -a devarr
for device in "${devices[@]}"
do
    devarr=($device)
    read dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q "${devarr[1]}://${devarr[2]}:${devarr[3]}@${devarr[4]}/camerainfo" | html2text |     gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')
```

Also, I tried the following based on a combo of some alternative code that was suggested to an earlier question, along with some other code I came across while researching, but it also doesn't work. However, it would massively simplify things if it did. Could this work and is a better solution?

```
while read -u 3 line
do
    read UUID protocol username passwd ip_address
    curl_call="${protocol}://${ip_address}:${username}@${passwd}/report"
    echo $curl_call

    read dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q "$curl_call" | html2text | gawk'/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=",";print new,old }')

done 3< test_data.txt
```

Any help much appreciated, as it's going to be a long night regardless! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you have not accepted any answer in the past. See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: `while IFS=',' read -r UUID protocol username passwd ip_address ; do ... done < test_data.txt`

Comment: @Costas how do I integrate that into my code, I'm only managing to get     the first line to read in.
while read -u 3 line
do
while IFS=','; do read -r UUID protocol username passwd ip_address
........
done
done
?

Comment: How to you put code in comments?

Comment: Hang on, I had my variables the wrong way round, I think i've got it

Comment: @Costas. I've tried this:
`while read line do; while IFS=',' do; read -r UUID protocol username passwd ip_address; done; curl_call="${protocol}://${username}:${passwd}@${ip_address}/report" echo $curl_call; done < test_data.txt` 
This isn't working. It's printing out the whole contents of the file to command line, but the variables are not being assigned properly

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand simple syntax?

```
while IFS=',' read -r UUID protocol username passwd ip_address
do
    curl_call="${protocol}://${username}:${passwd}@${ip_address}/report"
    echo $curl_call
done < test_data.txt
```

Comment: yes, but I haven't managed to encapsulate it correctly within the outer
`while read line ; do
... done`

Comment: `while read line
do;
while IFS=',' read -r UUID protocol username passwd ip_address
do curl_call="${protocol}://${username}:${passwd}@${ip_address}/report"
echo $curl_call
done
done < test_data.txt`
with only one do done, I get a syntax error

Comment: @jewfro Everything what you have done should be placed between `do` and `done` without any extra `while ... done`

Comment: So sorry, I have another problem. I already had set the OFS to "," in the gawk command, as date was splitting at first space.  With the url hardcoded it was working fine to read both dates in the way. After adapting it with your code, it's not working again
`while IFS=',' read -r UUID protocol username passwd ip_address
do
curl_call="${protocol}://${username}:${passwd}@${ip_address}/report"
echo $curl_call
read dateStrNew dateStrOld < <(curl -k -q "$curl_call" | html2text | gawk '/Newest Sequence/ { new=$3" "$4 }/Oldest Sequence/ {old=$3" "$4}END {OFS=","; print new,old }')`

Comment: This is what is outputting:

`newest 2015-04-05

oldest 09:53:29,2015-04-01 07:54:06`

instead of 

`newest 2015-04-05 09:53:29


oldest 2015-04-01 07:54:06`

Comment: @jewfro Let me to see 2 row in `curl -k -q "$curl_call" | html2text ` with `/Newest Sequence/` and `/Oldest Sequence/`

Comment: On the second curl call, dateStrNew =  "," dateStrOld is empty
The third call is the same as the first =  `newest 2015-04-05 oldest 09:53:29,2015-04-01 07:54:06`